# Не работает скрипт waypoints.js

Tags: jquery

Нужно анимировать секции лендинга с помощью animate.css, чтобы при прокручивании экрана до секции запускалась анимация элементов. Все подключил, но waypoints.js
нормально работать не хочет.
В HEAD страницы подключены скрипты:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/animate.css">
<script src="libs/jquery-3.2.1.min/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/waypoints/src/waypoint.js"></script>
```

В конце страницы выполняется скрипт следующего содержания:

```
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('.adv-img-cont').waypoint(function() {
            $('.advantages-section .adv-img-cont').addClass('animated zoomIn').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
                function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('animated zoomIn')
                })
        }, { offset: '50%'})
    });
</script>
```

На выходе получаю сообщение:

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).waypoint is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (sunny-turkey.html:278)
    at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

Подключение скриптов и стилей в другом порядке ничего не дает. Подскажите в чем проблема? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Скрипт лежит по указанному пути? + в  последней версии waypoints (если я нагуглил правильный скрипт) он используется без jquery

Comment: Да, все скрипты подключены корректно, иначе в консоли было бы соответствующее сообщение. Скорее всего вы правы, похоже что они убрали поддержку jquery. Странное решение.